# Unit testcases for data present in side the <h1> tag

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, istanbul

I wan to do testing for the element which are present in my react code using Unit testing through  mocha in Istanbul tool.

writing a unit testcases for h1 tag which consist of some heading, how we caan write aunit test case for this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: <Row className={classes['space-around']}>
                <h3 style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: '24px' }}>Hello React </h3>
   </Row>

I want Unit test cases on h3 tag using jest.